# Numpy: function that creates block matrices

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matrix

Say I have a dimension `k`. What I'm looking for is a function that takes `k` as an input and returns the following block matrix.

Let `I` be a k-dimensional identity matrix and `0` be k-dimensional square matrix of zeros

That is:

```
def function(k):
...
return matrix 

function(2) -> np.array([I, 0])

function(3) -> np.array([[I,0,0]
                         [0,I,0]])

function(4) -> np.array([[I,0,0,0]
                         [0,I,0,0],
                         [0,0,I,0]])

function(5) -> np.array([[I,0,0,0,0]
                         [0,I,0,0,0],
                         [0,0,I,0,0],
                         [0,0,0,I,0]])
```

That is, the output is a (k-1,k) matrix where identity matrices are on the diagonal elements and zero matrices elsewhere.

What I've tried:

I know how to create any individual row, I just can't think of a way to put it into a function so that it takes a dimension, `k`, and spits out the matrix I need.

e.g.

```
np.block([[np.eye(3),np.zeros((3, 3)),np.zeros((3, 3))],
          [np.zeros((3, 3)),np.eye(3),np.zeros((3, 3))]])
```

Would be the desired output for k=3

[scipy.linalg.block_diag](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.block_diag.html) seems like it might be on the right track...

Comment: `np.identity(k*k)[:-k]`?

Comment: The I's aren't ones, they're k-dimensional identity matrices

Comment: Is `k` the _shape_ of the array or its _dimensionality_???

Comment: the identity matrices have the shape (k,k)

Comment: Yes, I understand that but they line up to form a single long diagonal of ones.

Comment: Good point, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMO, `np.eye` already has everything you need, as you can define number of rows and columns separately.
So your function should simply look like

```
def fct(k):
    return np.eye(k**2-k, k**2)
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, this should work:

```
a = np.concatenate((np.eye((k-1)*k),np.zeros([(k-1)*k,k])), axis=1)
```

(at least, when I set `k=3` and compare with the `np.block(...)` expression you gave, both results are identical)

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can also try [`np.fill_diagonal`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fill_diagonal.html) such that you create the right shape of matrices and then fill in the diagonal parts.

```
def make_block(k):
    arr = np.zeros(((k-1)*k, k*k))
    np.fill_diagonal(arr, 1)
    return arr
```

Comment: The result should have shape `((k-1)*k, k*k)` (which is what you achieve with e.g. @PaulPanzer's `np.identity(k*k)[:-k]`), not `(k*k, (k+1)*k)`. It appears that `np.fill_diagonal(np.zeros(((k-1)*k, k*k)), 1)` is ever so slightly faster than the shorter solution.

Answer (score -1):

There are two interpretations to your question. One is where you are basically creating a matrix of the form [[1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0]], which can be mathematically represented as [I 0], and another where each element contains its own numpy array entirely (which does reduce computational ability but might be what you want).

The former:
`np.append(np.eye(k-1), np,zeros((k-1, 1)), axis=1)`

The latter (a bit more complicated):

```
I = np.eye(m) #Whatever dimensions you want, although probably m==n
Z = np.eye(n) 
arr = np.zeros((k-1, k)
for i in range(k-1):
    for j in range(k):
        if i == j:
            arr[i,j] = np.array(I)
        else:
            arr[i,j] = np.array(Z)
```

I really have no idea how the second one would be useful, so I think you might be a bit confused on the fundamental structure of a block matrix if that's what you think you want. Generally [A b], for example, with A being a matrix and b being a vector, is generally thought of as now representing a single matrix, with block notation just existing for simplicity's sake. Hope this helps!

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear that the 0's in my questions are k-dimensional square matrices of zeros. The identity matrices have the same dimension, so I dont see how I'm confused about block matrix notation. Paul Panzer's comment got it right, and corresponds to what I wrote in my examples. [[1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0]] cannot be mathematically represented as [I,0] if you define I and 0 as I did

Comment: Paul's answer and the first option I gave are identical. It can be mathematically represented that way, and is frankly a common form in applied linear algebra just to simplify notation, so I was just double checking what you were asking. Paul explains that they are basically the same thing, as I did, even though you seemed to argue against it. Just in case I gave you the CS pointer option of literally having arrays within arrays